# Compile Netbeans Web app with Java files (for deployment on XAMPP?)

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, compilation, xampp

1. I have NetBeans web application, with HTML, JavaScript, CSS files... and I have some Java files which I manage to call in the web application with DirectWebRemoting.
2. It is using NetBean's Tomcat.
3. After "Clean and Build", I get a WAR file in dist/
4. I put this WAR file into XAMPP/tomcat/webapps directory
5. Run the application with XAMPP Tomcat, but then the Java files would not work using XAMPP's Tomcat.

Question: How do I compile the build, so that when I put into XAMPP it would work? This is so that everytime I run the application I don't need to turn NetBeans on.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Tomcat Manager application to upload the  war file, dropping them directly in the /webapps directory doesn't work for me sometimes too.
Here's [a link](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html) to know more about using Tomcat Manager Application

Comment: Thanks, will try it! The Tomcat Manager Application prompted me for username and password though.

Comment: You'll have to assign manner-gui role for your tomcat user. If you don't have a user then make one. You'll have to refer tomcat-users.xml file for that, which is in config folder

Comment: Thanks, I managed to deployed it through the Tomcat Manager Application (in XAMPP)! But the web application still could not call the Java file. (When I run the application through NetBeans, the web application is able to call the Java files. But after this WAR deployment to XAMPP's Tomcat, the web application does not seem to call the Java files...)

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem, please let us know.. how you resolved it